# how to assign a value to mvc tempdata using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery, tempdata

I know how to get MVC TempData value using JQuery, but here I am trying to assign some value to TempData using JQuery. Is this possible to assign value to MVC TempData by using JQuery?

I am using MVC4 razor, by clicking on some text it should redirect to ActionResult Index () page then query to the DB where assigned TempData value then response to the same page. I don’t want to display my value in the address bar.

**View contains the following code**

```
<div onclick="getorder(1)">Test</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    getorder = function (id) {
        alert("Test Message");
        '@TempData["OrdID"]' = id;
        //here redirect to ActionResult
    }
});
```

**Controller ActionReslut Index()**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     ViewModel.CheckOut model = new ViewModel.CheckOut();
     if (TempData["ordID"] != null)
     {                
        int OrderID = int.Parse(TempData["OrdID"].ToString());                
        if (OrderID != 0)
        {
            model.OrderedLineItems = db.OrderedLineItemRepository.GetAllByRefID(f => f.OrderIDFlag == OrderID).ToList();
        }
     }
     return View(model);
 }
```

Comment: Why not use ajax? you can pass the value into the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Query Strings (GET Param), or you can put the javascript in the same HTML view (Not recommended).

Comment: I don't want to store my value in Query String, that is the reason i am preferring MVC TempData.

Comment: In that case, i would replace my JQuery function in a view helper, that way i can deal with variable in PHP level.

Comment: I am not comfortable with PHP script.Can you give code so that i will try to understand then implement in C#?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx

Comment: @reptildarat can you give ajax code to this problem? so that i will try to solve my problem in that way.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx not suit for my problem.